# What is <form action="#">?

Tags: html, forms, action

Ive seen people who put "#" in the action attribute for the form tag. could someone explain what that does?

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="Form" id="Form">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean when the form action attribute is "#" (number/pound symbol/sign/character)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862035/what-does-it-mean-when-the-form-action-attribute-is-number-pound-symbol-sig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An action of "#" indicates that the form stays on the same page, simply suffixing the URL with a #.

Comment: but where does the form send the data?

Comment: It all make sense now! Thanks :)

Comment: form sends the data to same page!! like recursive kind.. in some cases we handle the form data using ajax, etc.. then we dont need action, but it shouldn't be empty(best practise). in such a case we use #

Answer (score 1):

It resolves to the top of the current URL (eliminating any existing fragment id on the URL).

Answer (score 0):

Simply to stay in current page, in other terms avoiding page navigations

Answer (score 0):

That is an URL where the server part is empty, there is a bookmark separator, and the bookmark is empty.

The URL that will be used is the same as the current page.

When the response from posting the form arrives, the bookmark will be added to the URL (the bookmark is never sent to the server) and the empty bookmark is the top of the page. As the page is already loaded with the top of the page at the top of the window, the bookmark has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

As others replied,it will stay in the current page. Apart from the form tag we can use "#" in  tag as well. Using # we can create a link to another section of the same page.