# what does the hash mean in action="#" in html form tag

Tags: html

What does it mean for action="#" in the html form tag.
For example,

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="demoForm" id="demoForm">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Demo: Checkboxes Sharing Same Name</legend>

    <p>Check the types of sports or fitness activities you engage in on a regular basis.</p>

    <p>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="cycling" /> cycling</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="running" /> running</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="sports[]" value="other" /> other</label>
    </p>

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'#' submits form action url to itself(your page url where the form resides).
Mostly used for dummy purposes and same page form submissions, although there are better techniques out there.
Have a look at this answer

[what does it mean form action attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862035/what-does-it-mean-when-the-form-action-attribute-is-number-pound-symbol-sig)

Answer (score 1):

`#` means no outer redirection. In other words no link to another separate page. If need to refer then all should be referred only within that page itself.

in `<form>` tag:
`<form action="#">` means when click the submit button of the form don't have to redirect the collected data to any other page.

in `<a>` tag:
`<a href="#">` means when click on the link, don't redirect to any page. Just stay on the same page.

So simply in web development (in HTML) "#" means no linkage.  :)