# Why I am getting GET vars in a POST form?

Tags: html, post, get

I have this code:

```
<? 
$page = $_GET['page'];
$find = $_GET['find'];
?>

<form method="post" action="#">
  <input type="text" name="whatever" value="1">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Post this</button>
</form>
```

My initial URL is:
    htttp://www.someplace.com?page=1&find=lookfor

When sending the post form I am getting back "page" and "find" vars along the "whatever" input value. Why? Is this happening because my form action is "#"?

By the way, this is what I want, this saves me the work of posting hidden input values. But I want to be sure it is valid.

Comment: Try replacing `action="#"` by `action=""`. Does it solve the issue?

Comment: @AnisR. Not a problem for me, just want to know why this is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `action="#"`, you will submit the form to the **current URL**. Your GET vars are **part of this URL** so that is why you're getting them again.

More infos on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862035/what-does-it-mean-when-the-form-action-attribute-is-number-pound-symbol-sig).